# Does $\lim_{n\to\infty}S_n \leq S$ imply that $S_n < S$?

Tags: limits

Does $\lim_{n\to\infty}S_n \leq S$ imply that $S_n < S$ ?

Some something from proof I am working out bothering me.

Comment: only when $S_n$ is decreasing/converging

Comment: I think you meant *increasing*, @Aditya

Comment: ok thank yes, he meant increasing i think too

Answer (score 3):

If $S_n$ is an arbitrary sequence, then this is not the case.  For example, take the sequence
$$
\{1,0,1,1/2,1,3/4,1,7/8,1,\dots\}
$$

Comment: Your example doesn't seem to converge, contrary to the OP's assumption.

Comment: @Timbuc this example converges to $1$.

Comment: ok...but then all the elements of your sequence are less than or equal its limit.

Comment: @Timbuc which contradicts the given statement, the limit is $\le 1$ but there are terms which $=1$.

Comment: so if the sequence is increaibg this statement is right, correct ?

Comment: Indeed so, @DanZimm. Thanks, I must have missed that stron inequality sign.

Comment: @Timbuc all good - I do the same thing all the time!

Answer (score 3):

Let $S_n=1+\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$. Then $S_n\to 1\leq 1$ but $S_n$ with even $n$ will be greater than $1$. In fact, $\{S_n\}$ will alternate between above and below $1$.

Answer (score 2):

For a very simple counter example take

$$\frac{n+1}n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}1\;,\;\;\text{yet}\;\;\;\frac{n+1}n>1\;\;\;\;\forall\;n\in\Bbb N$$